# ¿cómo puedo hacer para llamar los métodos de la clase privada en la otra clase?

Tags: java

Tengo dos clases en java, una llamada estudiante, y la otra llamada escuela, y tengo la clase main. En la clase estudiante los atributos son privados pero ya hice uso de los constructores getter y setter para poder acceder a ellos en mi clase escuela pero no me funciona, ¿qué puedo hacer para que me reconozca el getAttribute();?, o mejor dicho, cómo puedo hacer para usar los atributos de una clase privada, en otra clase, para mandarlos a imprimir.

```
public class Estudiante {
    private int grado;
    private int edad;
    private String nombre;  

    public Estudiante(int grado, int edad, String nombre) {
        this.grado = grado;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getGrado() {
        return grado;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setGrado(int grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

El Principal problema es aquí, donde no me deja hacer uso del "`getAtributo()`" para acceder al atributo a través de los constructores, y así poder usarlo en la otra clase:

```
public class Escuela {
    public String nombre_escuela;
    public String ciudad;
    public int distrito;

    public Escuela(String nombre_escuela, String ciudad, int distrito) {
        this.nombre_escuela = nombre_escuela;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }

    public String getNombre_escuela() {
        return nombre_escuela;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public int getDistrito() {
        return distrito;
    }

    public void setNombre_escuela(String nombre_escuela) {
        this.nombre_escuela = nombre_escuela;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public void setDistrito(int distrito) {
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }

    public void informacion_estudiante(){
        System.out.println("Nombre del estudiante: "+getNombre()
        +"\nEdad: "+getEdad()+"\nGrado: "+getGrado()
        +"\nEscuela a la que asiste: "+nombre_escuela
        +"\nCiudad: "+ciudad
        +"\nDistrito: "+distrito);
    }
}
```

Esta es mi función principal donde sólo llamo el método

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Estudiante Estu = new Estudiante(8,13,"William Herrera");
        Escuela escu= new Escuela("Escuela Nacional Autónoma","Ciudad",5);

        escu.informacion_estudiante();
    }

}
```

psdt: Soy nueva en esto, y me gusta mucho la programación, estoy en la carrera de informática y acabamos de empezar a ver programación orientada a objetos y las clases virtuales no ayudan mucho.

Comment: Debes poner tu codigo, no una descripcion de tu codigo. Por supuesto no todo el codigo completo porque puede ser largo, pero si lo minimo que nos ayude a entender o visualizar el problema.

Comment: Además de lo dicho, debes agregar si tu código genera errores y en concecuencia el error

Comment: Una cosa mas... antes de intentar colocar tu codigo en los comentarios (a vecez pasa), tu codigo no debe ir aqui en los comentarios, debes editar la pregunta y poner dentro del cuerpo de la pregunta tu codigo, recuerda que si seleccionas todo tu codigo y le das al simbolo de las llaves ({}), lo formatearas automaticamente como codigo.

Comment: No te deja hacer uso de tu metodo getAtributo... quiza porque este no se encuentra creado?? (no veo que tengas en el código ningun metodo llamado getAtributo) ni tampoco donde intentes usarlo...

Comment: Otra cosa que puedo ver es que estas intentado usar metodos de otra clase como si hicieran parte de esa misma clase... (hay que fijarse en el metodo informacion_estudiante), no puedes hacer uso de los metodos de otra clase si la clase no extiende de la otra y si no llamas super tambien dentro del constructor... pero no hay necesidad de tantas complicaciones... te doy una pista, los metodos getNombre, getGrado y getEdad no pertenecen a la clase Escuela, sin embargo estas tratando de usarlos en la clase Escuela, pero estos hacen parte enrealidad de la clase Estudiante, creo que suena familiar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay cosas un poco inconclusas o confusas en tu código... por ejemplo dices que no te deja usar el método `getAtributo()` pero este no esta por ninguna parte creado en tu código ni tampoco lo estas llamando... así que asumo que te querías referir con el método `getAtributo` a cualquiera de los getters y setters que tienes de cualquiera de las dos clases.

Entonces miremos bien el codigo, en primeras tenemos la parte mas corta, el metodo principal:

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Estudiante Estu = new Estudiante(8,13,"William Herrera");
        Escuela escu= new Escuela("Escuela Nacional Autónoma","Ciudad",5);

        escu.informacion_estudiante();
    }

}
```

Esto esta perfecto así como esta y de hecho de antemano reviste tambien de una vez la clase `Estudiantes` y no hay problema alguna con ella, todo se encuentra correcto, así que concentrémonos entonces en la ultima clase que es la clase `Escuela`, donde en todo el código no tienes ningún inconveniente, excepto en esta parte especifica del código:

```
public void informacion_estudiante(){
    System.out.println("Nombre del estudiante: "+getNombre()
    +"\nEdad: "+getEdad()+"\nGrado: "+getGrado()
    +"\nEscuela a la que asiste: "+nombre_escuela
    +"\nCiudad: "+ciudad
    +"\nDistrito: "+distrito);
}
```

Donde tenemos 3 problemas:

- `getNombre` no existe en la clase `Escuela` y NO hace parte de ella.
- `getEdad` no existe en la clase `Escuela` y NO hace parte de ella.
- `getGrado` no existe en la clase `Escuela` y NO hace parte de ella.

Asi que hay 3 errores, estas intentando usar 3 metodos que no existen y que no hacen parte de una clase dentro de esa clase.

**El problema es pensar que todas las clases pueden hacer uso de cualquiera de sus metodos en cualquier parte sin tener que extender de estas o hacerlas estaticas o tener una referencia.**

Así que una forma fácil para arreglar este inconveniente es por ejemplo cambiar unas cuantas cosas para que tu metodo `informacion_estudiante` reciba y muestre la información con la que habías construido un objeto `Estudiante` anteriormente, para que posteriormente este objeto pueda hacer uso de sus métodos dentro de la clase `Escuela`, de la siguiente manera:

```
Estudiante Estu = new Estudiante(8,13,"William Herrera");
Escuela escu= new Escuela("Escuela Nacional Autónoma","Ciudad",5);

//Le tenemos que pasar un objeto estudiante ahora
escu.informacion_estudiante(Estu);
```

Debemos cambiar ahora los parametros que recibe el metodo `informacion_estudiante`, ahora deberemos recibir como parametro un `Estudiante`:

```
//Fijate que recibimos un nuevo parametro
public void informacion_estudiante(Estudiante est){
    ...
}
```

Y ahora tenemos que simplemente usar el nuevo parametro para usar sus metodos:

```
public void informacion_estudiante(Estudiante est){
    System.out.println("Nombre del estudiante: "+ est.getNombre()
    +"\nEdad: "+ est.getEdad()+"\nGrado: "+ est.getGrado()
    +"\nEscuela a la que asiste: "+ nombre_escuela
    +"\nCiudad: "+ ciudad
    +"\nDistrito: "+ distrito);
}
```

**Hay que fijarse bien en el código para notar los cambios (si que los hay).**

Con esto ya debe funcionarte el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho, has aclarado todas mis dudas, ya pude hacerlo, habia estado buscando en internet por horas.....

Comment: @May395 si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como aceptada pulsando en el icono de la parte superior izquierda. Saludos.